# DC powered USB wall faceplate

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, dc, usb-c, power-delivery

Looking to make a USB Power Delivery faceplate to install within a wall. Looking to feed the faceplate from a 48V DC Bus that I have available. Looking to get ideally x2 USB C connectors and x2 USB A connectors. I'm aware that USB C uses some form of handshake protocol to negotiate power between the source/sink - and that a chip is required for this.

I would be ideally looking to charge a laptop off of this USB C port - which will require approx 3A at 20V to charge. Looking online I'm finding it quite difficult to find chipsets that will support the range of devices I am looking to power (anything from a smartphone to a laptop) - for example:

https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusb1702.html

Which appears to have a current limit of 600mA and therefore will not work. Is there a better way to go about this - or a specific chipset I should be aware of that may help with this mini project?

Comment: an 48 -> 20V DC/DC 60W power supply – that's going to be large; probably significantly larger (and more expensive) than the very highly integrated laptop charger you know. Why not simply take that, throw it in the wall, connect it to a faceplate? Would only give you one USB-C port, but at least that will be high-power capable.

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products are off-topic for this site.

Comment: The big box home improvement stores has similar items to these in stock, basically adds a USB charge port to an outlet. Not sure if I saw USB C.